# Headless browser with mouseover event

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs with selenium to click a button. Unfortunately, that button is disabled, and only enabled when there's mouseover/click event in the real browser. Is there any way to simulate that in PhantomJS?

I tried ActionChains, but it still doesn't work (the button is still disabled):

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is not PhantomJS, but rather Actions.  When you use actions, you should link all of your actions together, and then perform the action.  In this case, it would be:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform();
```

Comment: I tried this but the button is still disabled. Using the real browser Firefox, I see that whenever I click out of the website the button is disabled. It's only enabled when the website has focus (using firebug they're mouseover/mouseout event)

Comment: Have you tried the code with a non-headless browser to see if PhantomJS your problem?

Comment: I've used ActionChains with phantom, and had it work.  My guess is that the javascript being performed on mouseover doesn't work properly with PhantomJS.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css(button))).perform();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we appreciate your input! Please edit your post so that it looks more like an answer rather than a comment, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more hints.